# Unable to create jira Bug using python

Tags: python, jira

I am using below code to create ticket in jira.
I am able to create only `TASK`. When i create `Bug` or `Story` I am getting below error .

```
issue_dict = {
    'project': {'key': 'TEST'},
    'summary': 'New issue from jira-python',
    'description': 'Look into this one',
    'issuetype': {'name': 'Bug'}
}

new_issue = jira.create_issue(issue_dict)

print(new_issue)
```

errors :

```
jira.exceptions.JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 400 url: https://soubhagyapradhan.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue
    
    response headers = {'Date': 'Sun, 20 Nov 2022 04:23:17 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Server': 'AtlassianEdge',
    'Timing-Allow-Origin': '*', 'X-Arequestid': '023a3f63bfd3ed36e1b1f23637fa115d', 'X-Aaccountid': '5c2cfc199760f569b62799f9', 'Cache-Control':
    'no-cache, no-store, no-transform', 'Expect-Ct': 'report-uri="https://web-security-reports.services.atlassian.com/expect-ct-report/atlassian-proxy", 
    max-age=86400', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=63072000; preload', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Xss-Protection': '1; 
    mode=block', 'Atl-Traceid': '8fa4c1f91d6f9fe1', 'Report-To': '{"endpoints": [{"url": "https://dz8aopenkvv6s.cloudfront.net"}], "group":
    "endpoint-1", "include_subdomains": true, "max_age": 600}', 'Nel': '{"failure_fraction": 0.001, "include_subdomains": 
    true, "max_age": 600, "report_to": "endpoint-1"}', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'}
    response text = {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"issuetype":"Specify an issue type"}}
```

Please take a look how can i solve this error

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the error, you can see it says:

> "errors":{"issuetype":"Specify an issue type"}

So clearly something must be wrong with how you've set `issuetype`.

---

Have you tried looking at the [API docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/#jira-rest-api-examples)? It seems you could try:

- Specifying the Issue Type via the `issuetypeNames` parameter rather than just `issuetype`; or
- That you should specify an Issue Type ID rather than an issue type name.

Note that in Jira the Issue Types can be customised, so the issue type that you're trying to create might not always exist / have the same name. You can try [getting all issue types for the user](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issue-types/#api-rest-api-3-issuetype-get) to see if that's the case.